# facebook asp.net page redirects - can't do response redirect

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication

I need some guidance please. I created a `default.aspx` page that displays the user's first name but also contains a button that redirect to a `result.aspx` page `onclick`. It seems  that every time I click on the button I get an infinite loop error. What should I do on `page_load` of `result.aspx` to get this work?

Here's my code from `default.aspx`:

```
string appId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string appSecret = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
FacebookCookie cookie = null;
FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient();
FacebookOAuthClient oAuth = new FacebookOAuthClient();
// FacebookWebClient apps = new FacebookWebClient();
FacebookApp apps = new FacebookApp();

string myRedirect_uri = "http://www.mydomain.com";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(apps.Session != null)
    //if (IsConnected())
    {
        display(apps.AccessToken);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=http://www.mydomain.com&scope=email");
        name.Text = "no connected";
    }


}
public bool IsConnected()
{
    if (cookie == null)
        cookie = FacebookCookie.GetCookie(appId, appSecret);
    return cookie != null && cookie.UserId != 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.SessionKey);
}
protected void display(string token)
{
    FacebookClient thisclient = new FacebookClient(token);
    dynamic dname = thisclient.Get("me");
    name.Text = dname.name;
    imgProfile.ImageUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + dname.id + "/picture?type=large";
}
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/resutl.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will be instantiated on every request:

```
FacebookApp apps = new FacebookApp();
```

Do you realize that? Is that what you want?

I ask because down in `Page_Load` you have:

```
if(apps.Session != null)
```

Which seems to always be true since apps is a new instance with presumably a new Session. In other words, your `else` block on `Page_Load` will never fire. But that's besides the point here.

So it seems to me that the app load fine, you click on the button, the `btn_Click` handler is called and the user is redirected to `resutl.aspx` and then `result.aspx` must be doing something that causes the user to be redirected to `default.aspx` like for example, perhaps checking if the user is authenticated or not.

What kind of authentication are you using?